# Pagefile keeps growing, but never fully utilised

Tags: windows, memory, ssd, virtual-memory, pagefile

My laptop runs Windows 10 Pro and has a 512GB SSD (~45GB free) and 16GB RAM.
My page file is set to 'automatically managed'.
Recently I've found that my pagefile keeps growing to the point where it takes up >40 GB and I end up having no free space, and have to restart. However, according to Performance Monitor the amount of the page file actually being used is always around 20-25% - i.e. when the pagefile size is 20GB, approximately 5GB is used. When the pagefile grows to 40GB, only around 10GB of it is being used.

When I try fixing the pagefile size to something like 20GB, Windows still refuses to fill up the pagefile. I end up using up all my RAM and getting black screen freezes.

Here is what the [Process Explorer Memory tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMaGk.png) says.

How do I make Windows use the pagefile more efficiently so that it doesn't keep growing uncontrollably? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The usage spikes may be too small to see. You could always not use "system managed" to see what happens.

Comment: Your drive is too full, which leads to issues like this & eventually an early death for the drive. The obvious workaround, until you can move some data off it, it to fix the pagefile size at 20GB.

Comment: If you launch Process Explorer. Can you add a screenshot of the system information - memory tab dialog?

Comment: Thanks all for your help so far, have added extra info to the post.

Comment: “Windows still refuses to fill up the pagefile.” – Again: The peaks are there. That doesn’t mean they are visible “to the naked eye”. // It looks like you simply need more RAM. The software you use also seems _exceptionally_ bad at managing its commit limit usage.

Comment: Generally, I set both maximum and minimum size of pagefile to the *same value*, rather than relying on automatic sizing, which avoids **HDD** fragmentation. However, for an **SSD**, that might cause undue wear.

Comment: Thanks Daniel and Dr, @DanielB do you know of any ways of identifying which software is not managing the commit limit usage well? Based on Task Manager it looks like Acrobat.exe and Chrome usually have higher commit sizes.